# Como Actualizar Los Items de un RecyclerView en el Patrón Master/Detail - Cuando se Elimina, Agrega o se Actualiza (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

En mi `MainActivity` tengo dos `fragments`, el primer `fragment` contiene la lista de artículos, el segundo `fragment` contiene el detalle del artículo, donde también puedo cargar un `fragment` para agregar un artículo.

Cuando agrego el artículo se guarda en una base de datos local **SQLite**, pero no se actualiza la lista con el nuevo ítem agregado.

Quisiera que me ayuden con un ejemplo, o me sugieran una web donde puedo encontrar la solución.

[image: Patrón Maestro Detalle - Android Studio]

He encontrado, código que se puede utilizar desde el adapter siempre y cuando haya una acción como un click.

añadiendo lo siguiente

```
mDataset.remove(holder.getPosition());

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Eso funciona perfectamente si implemento un botón en la lista y agrego el código en el evento onClick, pero mi problema se basa que yo guardo la información desde un fragment diferente y no tengo la menor idea cómo lograrlo desde el evento click del botón guardar que se encuentra en el fragment donde añado un artículo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar una libreria llamada EventBus, con ella lanzas un evento al bus desde el fragment en el que guardas el articulo y en el fragment de la lista te suscribes a ese evento.
Aqui hay un tutorial sobre como utilizar EventBus: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/articles/effective-android-components-communication-with-greenrobot-eventbus--cms-27654 Y aqui la documentación oficial:
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/

Comment: puedes editar tu pregunta y mostrar el codigo de tu MainActivity y del fragmento A.

Comment: Gracias, pero aún estoy aprendiendo y me gustaría saber la manera de realizar lo sin ayuda de una librería por ahora.

Comment: En ese caso puedes utilizar un callback entre los fragments.
[Aquí la documentación de google sobre el tema](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Puedes poner el código de el adaptador?

Comment: Muy bien lo voy chekar